# Summernote v0.8.15 icons not loading

Tags: summernote

I came across a problem wherein summernote icons are not loading properly.
How can I do this one?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to load icons properly in summernote 8.15
you need to include it in your css/scss files

```
ex. css/fonts.scss
/* summernote 8.15 need to include it font-face*/

@font-face {
  font-family: "summernote";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: auto;
  src: url('/fonts/font/summernote.eot');
  src: url('/fonts/font/summernote.eot?#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"), 
       url('/fonts/font/summernote.woff2') format("woff2"), 
       url('/fonts/font/summernote.woff') format("woff"), 
      url('/fonts/font/summernote.ttf') format("truetype");}
```

then in your assets, you need to copy the fonts folder of summernote 8.15

```
assets/
- css/
  --fonts.scss
-fonts/
  --font/
    ---summernote.eot
    ---summernote.woff2
    ---summernote.woff
    ---summernote.ttf
```

see summernote docs https://summernote.org/

Answer (score 0):

This relates to your font files not being in the right folder.

By default, summernote expects the `font` folder to be in the same folder where you're loading the css file.

So for example for `/css/summernote.css` the fonts would be expected in `/css/font/summernote.eot` because of the path given in `summernote.css`

If compiling using **SCSS**, you can modify the font path by changing the `$sni-font-path` in `summernote-icons.scss`.

Answer (score -1):

Open summernote-bs4.min.js file and replace the icons that are not displayed

like: before in file note-icon-chain-broken and after change icon fas fa-unlink.

Note: here your project support fas fa or fa fa or any other according replace icon.